# Scoped css for Nuxt.js layout

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working with nuxt and i have a header layout for my nav.
This nav has a background color of white.

On a special page, i want to make the nav background color transparent. (Only for this page)

I've tried those:

This will make the background transparent to all pages.(I don't want that)

```
<style lang="css">
nav {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

This won't work cause my nav it's not in this page, it's included from nuxt layout.

```
<style lang="css" scoped>
nav {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Also tried !important, but it doesn't work..

Do you got any suggestion beside making a new layout with header transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various solutions I can think of, with varying degrees of hackiness.

**Easist - most reliable** - direct DOM manipulation
This is the less Vue/Nuxt specific. You can just add a class to the element and then within the desire components correct lifecycle method you attach another class with the desired styles

**more work - still reliable** - Vuex store
Use a Vuex store to store any props you want to be passed from components up to layouts. Feels like it is overkill for simply setting background colors. But who knows what you also will want to set in the future and its not difficult to set up a Vuex store.

**more work - least realiable** - Router Guards
You can add specific route checks that set the color of the background when a specific route is reached or a route contains a certain string, etc. This is not a good solution because it has the highest chance of getting broken in the future if routes change.

Answer (score 0):

In the body of this special page include a class name:

```
<body class="special">
```

Then in your CSS include rules for nav that are only for this page:

```
body.special nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Forget to say that i'm using nuxt. So i can't set class for body only on this page.
But still.. increasing the specificity like in your example won't work. I have tried !important
PS: Should i press the "not useful" button as fast as you do?

Comment: @MSergiu You should think a bit before you accuse people of things they didn't do.

Comment: Sorry for that. You was the only one who replied, so i supposed that it was you. And thank you for trying to help ;)

Comment: @MSergiu you can conditionally set class for the body on the specific page, check this: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1662#issuecomment-370567465

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to refresh the page to see if that fixes the problem. (I also had the same problem as you, and then figured out that it might be a hot reload issue.)