# How to include local (not global) stylesheet file for each layout in Nuxtjs

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxtjs

Is it possible to import css-files to a separate layout so that styles are applied only to one layout without affecting others?

Comment: Duplicate of [scoped-css-for-nuxt-js-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536891/scoped-css-for-nuxt-js-layout)

Comment: Thanks, but it is necessary to include just css-files, but not to place styles in the layout component.

Comment: You can use `<style src="./my-component.css"></style>` rather than defining your CSS there itself, in your components.

Comment: @butttons, I tried this method, but the styles were imported globally anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I found this solution.

1. Rename ".css" files to ".scss".
2. In your layout add the wrapper block with custom class "my-class".

`layouts/AuthLayout`:

```
<template>
  <div class="auth-layout">
    <section>
      <Nuxt/>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

3. Then add a style section. This uses SCSS features and the v-deep directive.

`layouts/AuthLayout`:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
 .auth-layout {
   &::v-deep {
    @import '~assets/path/to/style.scss';
    @import '~assets/path/to/custom.scss';
    // ...
  }
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it would be helpful for somebody.
If your style files have `.css` extension you can put them on `static` directory and address in your layout `head` function or object in this way (my file is in `static/css/main.css` directory)

```
    return {
      link: [
         //you shouldn't mention ~/static itself
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/main.css' }, 
      ],
    };
```

if your file has `.scss` extension or any other preprocessor you can put it in `assets` directory cause webpack compile files on this directory.

Comment: how can i use wiyh scss files?

Answer (score 0):

credit to [this github answer](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/3877#issuecomment-1183166744).

If you define the css/scss in your static/assets directory, and import them in the layout within a style tag:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import '~/assets/layout.scss';
</style>
```

You can then scope the styles per layout using:

```
// nuxt.config.js
build: {
  extractCSS: false, // true causes duplicate css (false is the default)
  splitChunks: {
    layouts: true
  }
}
```